# Form submit is not prevented when trying to integrate VueJS with SemanticUI

Tags: javascript, vue.js, semantic-ui, vue-component

I'm trying to integrate SemanticUI with Vue and I have a Login component with a form in it.

I've added `v-on:submit.prevent="onSubmit"` to the form but when I press enter on one of the form's fields the form still submits and my method ie never called.

Basically what I'm trying to do is replicate the `on("submit"` event from jQuery.

Any idea what's the problem?

main.js

```
import Vue       from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import App       from "./App";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

new Vue({
    el        : "#app",
    template  : "<App/>",
    components: { App }
});
```

and Login.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="ui middle aligned center aligned grid">
        <div class="column">
            <h2 class="ui teal header">
                Login
            </h2>

            <form class="ui large form login" v-on:submit.prevent="onSubmit">
                <div class="ui stacked segment">
                    <div class="field">
                        <div class="ui left icon input">
                            <i class="cloud icon"></i>
                            <input type="text" name="hostname" placeholder="Hostname" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="field">
                        <div class="ui left icon input">
                            <i class="user icon"></i>
                            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="field">
                        <div class="ui left icon input">
                            <i class="lock icon"></i>
                            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="ui fluid large teal submit button">Login</div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "login",

        mounted: function() {
            this.$nextTick(function() {     
                jQuery(this.$el).find("form").form({
                    fields: {
                        hostname: {
                            identifier: "hostname",
                            rules     : [{
                                type  : "empty",
                                prompt: "Please enter the instance hostname"
                            }]
                        },

                        username: {
                            identifier: "username",
                            rules     : [{
                                type  : "empty",
                                prompt: "Please enter your username"
                            }]
                        },

                        password: {
                            identifier: "password",
                            rules     : [{
                                type  : "empty",
                                prompt: "Please enter your password"
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        },

        methods: {
            onSubmit: function(e) {
                alert("ok");
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Could you show the code you are using to submit the form? You don't appear to be using a standard `submit` input.

Comment: The from is submitted by pressing Enter while on one of those three inputs. With standard jQuery a `$(document).on("submit", "form", function(e) { });` works.

Comment: Are you able to change your Login button to an input and keep the styling: `<input type="submit" class="ui fluid large teal submit button" value="Login">`?

Comment: @craig_h Oh man, yessss. that did the trick. `<button type="submit" class="ui fluid large teal submit button">Login</button>` and it still looks the same. Somehow on the legacy app SemanticUI was triggering a form submit form JS even with the div which in combination with Vue didn't worked. Maybe some conflict or something, it's not clear yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A form will submit on ENTER key if it has one of the following:

- a `button` inside, *without* `type="button"`
- an `input` tag with `type="submit"`

Your form does not seem to have either of the above. But assuming you have a submit button elsewhere, here is how you can avoid form submit:

```html
<form onsubmit="return false;">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Host Name" v-model="hostName">
    <input type="text" placeholder="User Name" v-model="userName">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" v-model="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit form">
</form>
```

Note that the form has `onsubmit="return false;"` which prevents accidental submission.

This does not stop you from using a method in Vue component, initiated via a button using `@click="submitLoginForm()"`, to do the submission using `this.$http.post(...)`

Comment: Thanks! A button without the type attribute will have the form submitted! I totally forgot that.